# Google Cloud Console - This client ID is globally unique and is already in use

Tags: google-oauth, google-api-console

I have a very frustrating problem! We created a project on google cloud console and generated an android client id using our package-name and sha-1 but then we had to delete this project because it was created using a personal gmail account and we need to move to the company account, but now we CAN'T create the client id again, we get the message

"This client ID is globally unique and is already in use "

Our app is on google play so we can't change the base package or sha-1.

We don't have another project using the same package and sha-1.

We can't "undelete" the project because it has been deleted more than 7 days and we don't see the undelete option.

I made a lot of research and didn't find anything useful.

What should I do?

Google provides some support https://cloud.google.com/support/, but have I  to pay no less than 150/month to have an answer for something I think is a bug on cloud.google.com ???

Pay for a system bug! no way!

As I said this is very very frustrating. Any ideas ????

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few of the developers have encountered the issue when they delete the project without deleting that client id. We can fix it. :) Do make sure to look for any deleted projects or ask other members of your team who may have created the client id with the same details (most common reason).

Ping me through my [G+ profile](https://google.com/+NaveenAgarwal) if you need help.

Update: Dec 16, 2016: We have made some changes and most of you should not be seeing this message. Most of these errors were due to the fact that when a project is deleted they are soft deleted (and completely deleted after a few days) because we do allow a developer to undelete. There can only be one client id with a given package name and SHA1 hash of the cert and that is why you get the error.

Comment: I will contact you  via hangouts. Thanks!

Comment: It seems that I have the same issue, but now it claims about duplicate fingerprint http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24160011/the-signing-fingerprint-you-specified-is-already-used-by-another-android-oauth2

Comment: I have the same problem. Will it be okay to send you my app details on your G+ profile?

Comment: So, this is a very recurring problem with lots of developers? IMHO, that "Developers Console" needs a big fat warning about duplicate keys, plus an option to delete only the freaking Client ID.

Comment: @nvnagr I am having a similar issue can you contact me?

Comment: @nvnagr I have the same problem. Can you please help me too?

Comment: @nvnagr I also have the same problem.

Comment: @andy Ping me through my G+ profile, I'll need some info about the app and I can look up the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a problem in Google Drive apps while creating Client ID for the project etc, then let me make it easy for you. I had the same problem, i deleted some projects and after that it was not possible for me to run my app, because my project was deleted etc. So what i did, is that i **rename my project** package name in eclipse and after that i create new projects with SHA1 and my new package name. And so i got my solution.