# Google Developers Console- Unable to restore project to delete Client ID

Tags: android, console, undelete

I created a project a few months ago while playing around with leaderboards and achievements. Wasn't sure whether I wanted them or not. 
In the end I deleted the project off of the Google Developers Console and released my app without leaderboards or achievements.
I now want to add leaderboards and achievements to my app but get the classic Client ID is globally unique error. So I went into the Google Developers Console and tried to restore the old project but am getting an error message stating 
"You do not have permission to perform this action. Only project owners may delete or rename a project."
Yet I am the project manager.
What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. 
The new console is bugged and would not allow me to restore a project.
I used the old console and had no problem restoring my project and can now use everything properly. No need to change package or keystore. :D

Comment: how do i switch to the old console?

Comment: @clayton33 Did you figure out the old URL? I'm unable to restore as well.

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me right now.

I dont know solve the permission problem (only that happens when the deleted projects used Google Play Game Services).

About the client id error, you can try a workaround:

Change the package name if you like. If not:

Change the debug keystore. If can not or if it's production:

Contact google or wait deletion (a week?).

Further information, join the club:

https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=554

[Google Cloud Console - This client ID is globally unique and is already in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20980800/google-cloud-console-this-client-id-is-globally-unique-and-is-already-in-use?rq=1)

[Error when recreating a Client ID for an Android App in the API Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16659689/error-when-recreating-a-client-id-for-an-android-app-in-the-api-console)

Edited: I tried delete and regenerate debug.keystore, problem solved in my case as the sha1 fingerprint changes:

Delete your debug certificate under ~/.android/debug.keystore on Linux and Mac OS X; the directory is something like %USERPROFILE%/.androidon Windows.

The Eclipse plugin should then generate a new certificate when you next try to build a debug package. You may need to clean and then build to generate the certificate.

["Debug certificate expired" error in Eclipse Android plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194808/debug-certificate-expired-error-in-eclipse-android-plugins/2196397#2196397)

Comment: The app is in production, so I was hoping to not have to change the package name.
Also it seems to not be deleting itself. It has been over a month now and it is still listed under "projects pending deletion". 
I wish it would just finish deleting itself.

Answer (score 0):

Check this: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/projects/undelete

```
gcloud projects undelete <project-id>
```