# Google Developer Console - reuse deleted credentials

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, google-oauth, google-api-console

I accidentally deleted my production OAuth credential for my Android App, from the Google Developer Console.
When trying to add it back, using same SHA1 it says it can't, because the SHA1 is already in use. I've waited 10 days, and it is still not working.

My Question is, Is the only way to solve it is to create a new Keystore file ? 
that means I can't upload an update to Google Play! this is insane..
Google Support is now supporting only payed customers so emailing them is not an option.

Anyone has a better Idea?

Thanks a lot,
Giora.

Comment: Apologies if it's redundant, but did you check to make sure that this set of credentials don't already exist in other projects? The error you're seeing should be saying that sha1/package name combination has already been used to create a set of credentials, this can include in other project. Otherwise, there's not much else to do besides contact google support or use a new set of credentials (which doesn't seem viable in this case).

Comment: I did check, but will do it once more just to be  completely sure. I couldn't find a free way to contact google on that matter..

Comment: With the help of nvnagr I've found out that one of the employees already defined it.. I'm sorry for your time and thanks a lot for helping

Comment: I don't know what that means, but I'm having the exact same problem. Were you able to get this resolved?

Comment: I'm having the same problem too. How to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See
[Google Cloud Console - This client ID is globally unique and is already in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20980800/google-cloud-console-this-client-id-is-globally-unique-and-is-already-in-use/20993410#20993410)

As Andy mentioned, you can undelete a project and look for the client_id there (and delete it).
If that doesn't work, ping me through my G+ profile and I can have a look.

Update: Dec 14, 2015: If more of you ran into this issue during the last week, we are fixing it. If you need to create the client id urgently and can't wait till the end of the week, message me through my G+ profile.

Comment: Hi and thanks for taking the time to answer. I didn't delete the project. Just deleted the Android app credentials. I still have my web app credentials and can't afford deleting the project.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and sorry for taking your time just to find that this was our mistake...

Comment: what actually happened? I'm very confused, and your comments don't provide much help. I too would not like to delete my project and start over just for some credentials, but can't generate from current SHA1. What actually fixed your issue?

Comment: I have found out that someone already used this SHA1 key on another project which I was not part of,  So I could not see it in my console. After deleting the credentials that used this SHA1 from my collegue's project, I was able to use it on my project.